# Practical use for Laptop NFC

Tags: laptop, android, nfc

I have a computer with NFC and a Google Galaxy Nexus. Both support NFC. Unfortunately, Google has failed to come up with any way to use them, too much noise around the keyword `nfc`.

- Can I transfer files from (or to) the phone with NFC?

  - I've only seen this with windows phones, not Android
- I'm an android developer/hacker. Can I `adb` over nfc?
- Can I lock my computer with my phone as the key?

I know tool suggestion requests are frowned upon, but the complete utter lack of (discoverable) tools seems to justify this. Any suggestions?

Comment: What operating system is your laptop running?

Comment: Windows & Fedora. Dual Boot. Also various linux VMs, Ubuntu, Arch, Fedora, Android etc.